# Perl Mojolicious stash dump

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How do I dump out the stash in perl

```
my $my_data =  {
    'me'    =>  {
        'admin' => 'rhaen',
        'desc'  => 'webserver'
    },
    'you' => {
        'admin' => 'hazel',
        'desc'  => 'mailserver'
    }
};
stash(mydata => $my_data);
print Dumper (stash 'mydata');
```

How do I print mydata me admin.  I have tried `print Dumper (stash 'mydata me'); print Dumper (stash 'mydata'=>['me']);`
Nothing seems to work. Trying to troubleshoot why data is changing.

Comment: Side note: Mojo::Util provides a 'dumper' function which is a simple wrapper of Data::Dumper with some nice settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following in [Mojolicious::Lite](http://p3rl.org/Mojolicious::Lite):

```
get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->stash(mydata => $my_data);
    use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($c->stash('mydata')->{me}{admin});
};
```

The output was

```
$VAR1 = 'rhaen';
```